# RegisterUserNotificationSettings interferes with web requests

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, push-notification

When I call `RegisterUserNotificationSettings` and there are web requests made around the call then after I click on either "Don't Allow" or "Allow" I get errors that say, "A task was cancelled."

So, first this...

```
var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
                UIUserNotificationType.Badge |
                UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                new NSSet());

 UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
```

And then after the dialog has disappeared, existing web requests are apparently cancelled.

Any ideas why there'd be this conflict? It seems to be a threading issue.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed this by making sure there's a small time gap between calling `RegisterUserNotificationSettings` and making web requests. e.g. call it before a view controller that makes web requests is created or call it after some web requests have finished.

It must be called on the UI thread else the alert box doesn't appear and it appears to stomp over existing web requests or web requests that start in-between it being called and the dialog appearing.

What a rude API call.